# Нативный php. Не работает namespace use

Tags: php, namespace

Не создается символическая ссылка при использовании use.

file `index.php`

```
use \Folder\Aa;
Aa::test();
$test = new Aa();
```

file `Folder/Aa.php`

```
namespace  Folder;
class Aa
{
    static function test()
    {
        $a = 3;
        echo $a;
    }
}
```

Выбрасывает ошибку

> Fatal error: Class 'Folder\Aa' not found in /home/ademidko/www/first.local/index.php

Я изменял `namespace Аа.php`, пробовал так `"use \Folder"` и т.д., но все равно не работает.

Comment: А как вы подключаете `Аа.php` в `index.php`?

Comment: При подключении файла через include к примеру все работает.
Но в мануале http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.importing.php прописано что должна создаватся символическая ссылка на файл

Comment: Использование `use` не освобождает вас от необходимости подключать файл.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, проблема в том, что у Вас не определен загрузчик классов.
Попробуйте в `index.php` объявить [автолоадер](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload.php)

Что-то типа

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

// project-specific namespace prefix
$prefix = 'Foo\\Bar\\';

// base directory for the namespace prefix
$base_dir = __DIR__ . '/src/';

// does the class use the namespace prefix?
$len = strlen($prefix);
if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
    // no, move to the next registered autoloader
    return;
}

// get the relative class name
$relative_class = substr($class, $len);

// replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
// separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
// with .php
$file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';

// if the file exists, require it
if (file_exists($file)) {
    require $file;
}
});
```